# Add Owner and Date range to aggregated table

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a need to be able to filter the below agg table by owner and then further split the table into forecast months.

As yet i am unable to find and documents to help me acheive this please could somebody help outline the steps nessasary to complete

below are images of the current output and what i hope to acheive

Current
[image]

Goal
[image]

Controller

```
public class ForecastListController {

    private String GroupParameter = 'ProductFamily';
    private date todaydate = date.today();

        }

        public List<AggregateResult> getForecastingItem() {

            List<AggregateResult> results = Database.query('SELECT SUM(AmountWithoutAdjustments) total, ProductFamily FROM ForecastingItem ' + ' Group BY ' + GroupParameter);

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastListController">

<apex:pageBlock >

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ForecastingItem}" var="FI">

         <apex:column value="{!FI['total']}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI['ProductFamily']}"/>


    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: what are the division 1 and 2 and 3 values? will these fields will be group by ownerId and sum of any fields?

Comment: Division at the moment is a nice to have each opportunitylineitem related to a forecast item has a division aswell as product family the idea would be to show the sum of amount with out adjustments based on these feilds and then the total sum at the end, the whole table should be filter by owner